# Question on Pyomo Transport/Shipping issue

Tags: pyomo

I am learning pyomo and practicing an exercise about shipping problem with conditions below:

1. The shipment can either directly deliver from source cities to the destination or through a depot (source city -> depot -> destination)
2. The way of shipping will be selected based on least cost consumed
3. Every Depot has its own capacity limitation

I tried to use pyomo to solve this question, however, no solution can be figured out.
Please give me some advice and direction why the codes didnt work. Thank you!

```
import pyomo.environ as pyomo
import numpy as np

supply = dict({'Liverpool': 150000,
               'Brighton': 200000})

through = dict({'Newcastle': 70000,
                'Birmingham': 50000,
                'London': 100000,
                'Exeter': 40000,
                'Liverpool': 150000,
                'Brighton': 200000
                })

demand = dict({'C1': 50000,
               'C2': 10000,
               'C3': 40000,
               'C4': 35000,
               'C5': 60000,
               'C6': 20000})

cost = dict({
    ('Liverpool', 'Newcastle'): 0.5,
    ('Liverpool', 'Birmingham'): 0.5,
    ('Liverpool', 'London'): 1.0,
    ('Liverpool', 'Exeter'): 0.2,
    ('Liverpool', 'C1'): 1.0,
    ('Liverpool', 'C3'): 1.5,
    ('Liverpool', 'C4'): 2.0,
    ('Liverpool', 'C6'): 1.0,
    ('Brighton', 'Birmingham'): 0.3,
    ('Brighton', 'London'): 0.5,
    ('Brighton', 'Exeter'): 0.2,
    ('Brighton', 'C1'): 2.0,
    ('Newcastle', 'C2'): 1.5,
    ('Newcastle', 'C3'): 0.5,
    ('Newcastle', 'C5'): 1.5,
    ('Newcastle', 'C6'): 1.0,
    ('Birmingham', 'C1'): 1.0,
    ('Birmingham', 'C2'): 0.5,
    ('Birmingham', 'C3'): 0.5,
    ('Birmingham', 'C4'): 1.0,
    ('Birmingham', 'C5'): 0.5,
    ('London', 'C2'): 1.5,
    ('London', 'C3'): 2.0,
    ('London', 'C5'): 0.5,
    ('London', 'C6'): 1.5,
    ('Exeter', 'C3'): 0.2,
    ('Exeter', 'C4'): 1.5,
    ('Exeter', 'C5'): 0.5,
    ('Exeter', 'C6'): 1.5
})

cost_total = {}
for city_from in supply.keys():
  for city_through in through.keys():
    for city_to in demand.keys():
      if city_from == city_through:
        cost_total[(city_from , city_through , city_to)] = 0 + cost.get((city_through , city_to) , 9999)
      else:
        cost_total[(city_from , city_through , city_to)] = cost.get((city_from , city_through) , 9999) + cost.get((city_through , city_to) , 9999)

supplier = supply.keys()
througher  = through.keys()
demander = demand.keys()

model = pyomo.ConcreteModel()

model.i = pyomo.Set(initialize = supplier , doc = 'City From')
model.j = pyomo.Set(initialize = througher , doc = 'City Through')
model.k = pyomo.Set(initialize = demander , doc = 'City To')

model.s = pyomo.Param(model.i , initialize=supply, doc='Supply by City')
model.t = pyomo.Param(model.j , initialize = through , doc = 'through / warehouse')
model.d = pyomo.Param(model.k , initialize=demand , doc='Demand by City')

model.cost = pyomo.Param(model.i , model.j , model.k , initialize=cost_total , doc = 'total cost')
model.x = pyomo.Var(model.i , model.j , model.k , bounds = (0 , None))

def supply_rule(model, i):
  return sum(model.x[i,j,k] for j in model.j for k in model.k) <= model.s[i]
model.supply = pyomo.Constraint(model.i, rule=supply_rule, doc='Observe supply limit at plant i')

def demand_rule(model, k):
  return sum(model.x[i,j,k] for i in model.i for j in model.j) == model.d[k]  
model.demand = pyomo.Constraint(model.k, rule=demand_rule, doc='Satisfy demand at market j')

def depot_cont(model , j):
  return sum(model.x[i , j , k] for i in model.i for k in model.k) <= model.t[j]
model.through_cont2 = pyomo.Constraint(model.j , rule = depot_cont)

def objective_rule(model):
  return sum(model.cost[i,j,k]*model.x[i,j,k] for i in model.i for j in model.j for k in model.k)
model.objective = pyomo.Objective(rule=objective_rule, sense=pyomo.minimize, doc='Define objective function')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code (unmodified) appears to be working for me.

Realize there are a couple ways to set this up, which is a larger discussion...  In your case you enumerated all possible routes, and snuck in a zero-cost option for the direct routes and added high cost for infeasible routes, which is fine.  On a larger problem, or more complicated network, the standard way to approach this is as a network flow problem with flow-balance constraints at all the nodes (cities).

Anyhow, your question isn't too clear on what "isn't working".  I added this to the end of your code:

```
solver = pyomo.SolverFactory('glpk')
result = solver.solve(model)
print(result)

for ijk in model.x.index_set():
  if model.x[ijk]:
    print(f'ship : {ijk} qty: {model.x[ijk].value}')
```

and it produced this result, which passes 1st level sanity check, but I didn't look at it too closely...

```
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 198500.0
  Upper bound: 198500.0
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 15
  Number of variables: 73
  Number of nonzeros: 217
  Sense: minimize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  Termination condition: optimal
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 0
      Number of created subproblems: 0
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.007380008697509766
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

ship : ('Liverpool', 'Liverpool', 'C1') qty: 50000.0
ship : ('Liverpool', 'Liverpool', 'C6') qty: 20000.0
ship : ('Brighton', 'Birmingham', 'C2') qty: 10000.0
ship : ('Brighton', 'Birmingham', 'C4') qty: 35000.0
ship : ('Brighton', 'Birmingham', 'C5') qty: 5000.0
ship : ('Brighton', 'London', 'C5') qty: 55000.0
ship : ('Brighton', 'Exeter', 'C3') qty: 40000.0
[Finished in 579ms]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I mean 'no solution can be figured out' is really no feasible solution. But I doubt it is because I am using CBC instead of GLPK during the calculation. Glad to know that it works when using GLPK as the solver. Thanks again!